# onclick is not working

Tags: javascript, html

```
   var rowcount = 0;

 function addrow() {
     rowcount++;
     console.log("nis" + rowcount);
     if (rowcount >= 2) {

         return false;
         rowcount = 0;

     }
     document.getElementById("myTableData").style.display = "block";
     var el = document.createElement('input');
     el.type = 'text';
     el.name = 'kname' + rowcount;
     var hid = document.createElement('input');
     hid.type = 'hidden';
     hid.name = 'hid';
     hid.value = rowcount;
     var del = document.createElement('input');
     del.type = 'button';
     del.name = 'delll';
     del.value = '';
     del.style.width = '30px';
     del.style.height = '26px';
     del.style.border = 'none';
     del.style.outline = 'none';
     del.style.background = 'url(./images/del-hover.png) no-repeat';
     del.onclick = function () {
         tr.parentElement.removeChild(tr);
         rowcount--;
         if (rowcount == 0 || rowcount >= 2) {
             document.getElementById("myTableData").style.display = "none";
             rowcount = 0;
         }
     };
     var el_r = document.createElement('input');
     el_r.type = 'radio';
     el_r.name = 'kgender' + rowcount;
     el_r.value = 'female';
     el_r.defaultChecked = true;
     var el_r2 = document.createElement('input');
     el_r2.type = 'radio';
     el_r2.name = 'kgender' + rowcount;
     el_r2.value = 'male';
     var obj1 = document.createTextNode("Female");
     var obj2 = document.createTextNode("Male");
     var objLabel = document.createElement("label");
     objLabel.htmlFor = el_r.id;
     objLabel.appendChild(el_r);
     objLabel.appendChild(obj1);
     var objLabel2 = document.createElement("label");
     objLabel2.htmlFor = el_r2.id;
     objLabel2.appendChild(el_r2);
     objLabel2.appendChild(obj2);
     var el_s = document.createElement('select');
     el_s.name = "day1" + rowcount;
     el_s.onchange = function () {
         value_d = el_s.options[el_s.selectedIndex].value;
     };
     for (var i = 1; i < 32; i++) {
         var j = i;
         j = document.createElement('option');
         j.text = i;
         j.value = i;
         el_s.appendChild(j);
     }
     var month = new Array("January", "Februray", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December");
     var el_sm = document.createElement('select');
     el_sm.name = "month1" + rowcount;
     el_sm.onchange = function () {
         var valuem = el_sm.options[el_sm.selectedIndex].value;
     };
     for (var i = 0; i < month.length; i++) {
         var j = i;
         j = document.createElement('option');
         j.text = month[i];
         j.value = i + 1;
         el_sm.appendChild(j);
     }
     var el_sy = document.createElement('select');
     el_sy.name = "year1" + rowcount;
     el_sy.onchange = function () {
         var valuey = el_sy.options[el_sy.selectedIndex].value;

     };
     for (var i = 2013; i > 1950; i--) {
         var j = i;
         j = document.createElement('option');
         j.text = i;
         j.value = i;
         el_sy.appendChild(j);
     }
     var table = document.getElementById("myTableData");
     var tableBody = document.createElement('TBODY');
     table.appendChild(tableBody);
     var tr = document.createElement('TR');
     tableBody.appendChild(tr);
     var td = document.createElement('TD');
     td.width = '175';
     td.appendChild(el);
     tr.appendChild(td);
     var td = document.createElement('TD');
     td.width = '245';
     td.appendChild(objLabel);
     td.appendChild(objLabel2);
     tr.appendChild(td);
     var td = document.createElement('TD');
     td.width = '245';
     td.appendChild(el_s);
     td.appendChild(el_sm);
     td.appendChild(el_sy);
     tr.appendChild(td);
     var td = document.createElement('TD');
     td.width = '20';
     td.appendChild(del);
     tr.appendChild(td);
     var td = document.createElement('TD');
     td.width = '10';
     td.appendChild(hid);
     tr.appendChild(td);
     myTableData.appendChild(table);
 }
```

**my html**

```
<td colspan="4">
    <div id="myTableData" style="display:none;">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td width="175">NAME</td>
                <td width="245">&nbsp;Gender</td>
                <td width="245">Date of Birth</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</td>
<td colspan="2">
    <div class="addkidbg" onClick="addrow()" />ADDKID</div>
</td>
```

when i click on the addrow button its show me the three rows but i need the user to click only one time , if the user delete  row and column name should be gone but if i click on addrow button twice and then click on the delete button .......den its showing me the column name . I want the whole part should b gone if the user delete the row and it can't clicked more than once

Comment: I recommend you to use the HTML DOM methods for adding/removing table content. See the following:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_table_insertrow.asp and http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_table_deleterow.asp

Comment: but i m working in a php language

Comment: Ermm.. In your question.. That definitely is not PHP..

Answer (score 0):

```
function addrow() {
    rowcount++;
    console.log("nis" + rowcount);
    if (rowcount >= 2) {
        rowcount = 0;
        return false;
    }
}
```

```
<div class="addkidbg" onClick="return addrow();" />ADDKID</div>
```

Try this code. Your function returns a value so write the return first on onclick event

Comment: if i click on addkid twice and after that i clicked on delete button ..........then NAME , GENDER and DATE OF BIRTH  row is not deleted